# JavaScript REGEX: How to pluck certain matches out of string?

Tags: javascript, regex

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eABbj/?editors=101

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-person">
  <%= name %> is <%= age %> years old. He works as a <%= occupation %>.  
</script>
```

JS:

```
String.prototype.template = function(data) {
    var tags = this.match(/\<%=(.+?)%\>/);
    console.log(tags);
};

document.getElementById('tpl-person').innerHTML.template({
    name: 'TK',
    age: 25,
    occupation: 'Web Developer'
});
```

the console log of the above is:

Output is:

```
["<%= name %>", " name ", index: 3, input: "↵  <%= name %> is <%= age %> years old. He works as a <%= occupation %>."]
```

I need it to be just:

```
["<%= name %>", "<%= age %>", "<%= occupation %>"]
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `g` modifier: `/<%=(.+?)%>/g`

This will give you an array of matches, rather than the first match and its subpatterns.

EDIT: That said, you're probably going to want a replace:

```
return this.replace(/<%=\s*(.+?)\s*%>/g,function(_,key) {
    return data[key] || "##"+key+"##";
    // that || and the bit after it offer a fallback so you can see failed tags
});
```